# Why is mutableCopy here?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray

I'm studying [Your Second iOS App](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/) by Apple. This project is based on ARC.

And while studying the example, I had a question concerning the following code from the example:

```
// header
@interface BirdSightingDataController : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *masterBirdSightingList;

@end

// implementation
- (void)setMasterBirdSightingList:(NSMutableArray *)newList {
    if (_masterBirdSightingList != newList) {
        _masterBirdSightingList = [newList mutableCopy];
    }
}

- (void)initializeDefaultDataList {
    NSMutableArray *sightingList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.masterBirdSightingList = sightingList;

    …
}
```

I don't know why this code overrode the default setter method of `masterBirdSightingList`.

The `masterBirdSightingList` property is of type `NSMutableArray` and is copied to the `_masterBirdSightingList` instance variable, which is of type `NSMutableArray` too. I think this is perfect.

Why is `_masterBirdSightingList = [newList mutableCopy];` here? Just in case `setMasterBirdSightingList:` is called with an argument of type `NSArray`?

Comment: I would say yes, it is to account for the case where a static array is passed in. Because masterBirdSightingList is declared as a mutable array, this code enforces that, preventing problems when code elsewhere tries to mutate an NSArray

Comment: What is interesting is that this is necessary even if the caller passes a mutable array to the setter.

Comment: Does the `copy` flag matter at all here?  I was under the impression it's just there to tell the compiler how to synthesize property accessors, and since they're not being synthesized here...

Comment: The copy flag will not matter here, it is purely for the benefit of the person reading the header.

Comment: Because it's a `copy` property, and the item is mutable, it must be copied -- it's written in the contract.  If it were a `strong` property instead then no copy would be required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is needed because the default implementation will simply call `copy` and you will end up with an immutable array instead of a mutable one.

Comment: Just to clarify further, calling the `copy` method on an `NSMutableArray` actually returns the copy as an immutable `NSArray`, not another `NSMutableArray`.